# Samsung Galaxy A11. Turn on 64 bit node?

Tags: samsung, hardware, processor

I wanted to purchase a 64-bit android smartphone. I looked at the processor used on the Galaxy A11. It is a 64-bit ARM Cortex-A53. And I bought this phone.
Looks like I made a mistake. Android on the Galaxy A11 runs in 32-bit mode.
Is it possible to switch the phone to 64-bit mode?

Comment: Why do you think that your phone is running a 32bit OS?

Comment: @Robert. Thanks for your interest.
    **1.** It says so here: pulse2.com/samsung-galaxy-a11-pros-and-cons "The Galaxy A11 runs in 32-bit mode in order to keep the memory usage low."
    **2**. This https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evo.inware program detects "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi". And no arm64-v8a.
    **3.** Programmatically, in Android studio "Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS;" contains {"armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"}. And "Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS" is empty.

Comment: Well then your phone really has only 32 bit support. The main problem is that you can't switch the phone to 64bit Mode because every executable file of your installed OS is 32bit. Changing would require installing a complete new OS which means you need to unlock/root the device and fine a custom ROM that is built to support 64bit.